# Adjust grid height to available screen without scrollbar

Tags: html, css, css-grid

What grid property should I use to keep the grid perfectly inside the screen?

Using `height: 100vh;` on `.wrapper` adjusts the height, but it introduces the scrollbars. To remove the unwanted scrollbars, I tried setting `body{margin:0;}` but I want to have a margin surrounding the entire grid without producing the scrollbars. I'm sure this is an easy fix, but please help me!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/reiallenramos/pen/yzroxe

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 8px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/5;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 3/5;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.item4 {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 3/5;
}

.item5 {
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 3/6;
}

.item6 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 5/7;
}

.item7 {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 5/7;
}

.item8 {
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 6/7;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Major browsers normally set a default margin on the `body` element. It's usually 8px, as [recommended by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html).

Therefore, when setting the `body` element or another container to `height: 100%`, a vertical scrollbar will render because there is an overflow condition:

```
100% + 8px > the viewport height
```

The simple workaround is to override the browser's default rule with your own:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

However, in this case, you want the gap around the main container. You don't want the scrollbar.

Then simply replace `margin` with `padding`, and use `box-sizing: border-box`.

With `box-sizing: border-box`, padding and borders (but not margins) are factored into the content length.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

/* NEW */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 8px;
  padding: 8px; /* NEW */
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/5;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 3/5;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.item4 {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 3/5;
}

.item5 {
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 3/6;
}

.item6 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 5/7;
}

.item7 {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 5/7;
}

.item8 {
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 6/7;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
  <div class="item item7">7</div>
  <div class="item item8">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works like magic! But what does the `*` in `* { box-sizing: border-box;}`  mean? I'm new to webdev and this is my first encounter of it.

Comment: The asterisk (`*`) is the universal selector. It means that the rule applies to all elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors

Answer (score 1):

Other than setting the margin on html, body, to 0, the only thing I found that would work is this:

```
html, body {
  height: 96vh;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. 96vh produces too much "margin" on the bottom, so I'll use 98vh for now. Still waiting for other ideas

Answer (score 1):

You have to subtract extra margin from your *wrapper*

`calc(100vh - 16px)`

No need to use 100% on body then.

Comment: is it 16 because of 8 default margin on top and bottom? thanks for this. I can just write a formula for determining that extra margin to avoid magic numbers.